# Building an ANN Model for Multiclass Image Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, image-classification

I am trying to create a baseline ANN and an improved ANN model and compare their effectiveness in image classification. I have a train and test dataset made up of images of fruits (apple, banana, orange, tomato). The original images were 480 x 320 but I reshaped and transformed them into a 1D Array.

Below is the code for the transformation via data generator UDF.

```
import os
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def train_generator_func(info=False, image=False):
train_data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2,
                                                                           zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
    train_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory('data/Train', target_size=(68, 46),
                                                               batch_size=32, class_mode='sparse')
    if info:
        print('The image shape of each training observation is:', train_generator.image_shape)
        print('\n We can see how:')
        for i in range(len(train_generator.class_indices)):
            print(list(train_generator.class_indices.keys())[i],
                  'is labeled as', list(train_generator.class_indices.values())[i])

    if image:
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
        for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
            img, label = train_generator.next()
            _ = ax.set_title(f'Label = {np.argmax(label[i])}')
            _ = ax.imshow(img[i])
        plt.show()
    return train_generator
```

Test label UDF

```
def test_label_func():
"""
:return: returns a vector with the labels of the test files
"""
data_path = os.path.join('data/Test', '*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)

test_label_fruit = list()
test_label = list()
label = None
for f in files:
    photo = re.sub(r"data/Test/", "", f)
    photo = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]", photo)
    photo = ''.join(photo)
    photo = re.sub(r"png", "", photo)
    if photo == 'Apple':
        label = 0
    if photo == 'Banana':
        label = 1
    if photo == 'Orange':
        label = 2
    if photo == 'Tamotoes':
        photo = 'Tomato'
test_label.append(photo)
return files, test_label
label = 3
test_label_fruit.append(photo)
test_label.append(label)
return files, test_label, test_label_fruit
```

Building ANN Model

```
#ANN Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from train_test_split import train_generator_func
from train_test_split import test_label_func
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

train_generator = train_generator_func(info=True)
files, test_label, test_label_fruit = test_label_func()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3128, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (100096,3)))
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)) #Dropout Layer to help avoid overfitting
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation = 'softmax')) #Dense Layer, Units = # of Classes 4
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

This Returns as Expected

```
Found 12834 images belonging to 4 classes.
The image shape of each training observation is: (68, 46, 3)

 We can see how:
Apple is labeled as 0
Banana is labeled as 1
Orange is labeled as 2
Tomato is labeled as 3
```

When I try to fit the model - I receive this error:

```
model.fit(train_generator, epochs =1)
```

> > InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [100096,4] and labels shape [128]      [[node
> > sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
> > (defined at :1) ]]
> > [Op:__inference_train_function_26958]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Additionally, conceptually, how do you set the number of neurons for the ANN model and how would I determine how many to set? I feel like this is where the error is but I am not sure.

Comment: To me sounds like you forgot to one-hot encode your labels.

Comment: Ah of course, you set the class mode to sparse.

Comment: @dataenthusiast93, Can you try as `model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])`?